# With what hook do I remove WooCommerce existing Product Data Tab form fields?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters, hooks

When editing a Woocommerce product in wp-admin there is a Product Data section with vertical tabs each of which has its own form fields to fill out.

A plugin has added fields that I don't want to the General tab.

What filter hook would I use to access a tabs field array and modify it as needed? (remove it)

Comment: which plugin has added these tabs?

Comment: Product Vendors, a premium plugin, has added a form field to the General tab called "Commission". Specifically, it's one of 3 areas where comission can be controlled, and this one is at the per product level. I want that removed so that nothing can override the setting at the global level. But, they seem to be hooking into default wordpress functionality, so I figured I'd call a separate hook with the lowest priority to undo it. I don't see where PV provides their own hooks when creating that field.

Answer (score 0):

You find the code for the general tab in the file [includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-product-data-general.php](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woocommerce/tags/3.4.2/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-product-data-general.php). In this file WooCommerce defined some do_action hooks. Maybe your plugin used one of them.

[image: WooCommerce Product metabox]

Hooks:

1. woocommerce_product_options_pricing
2. woocommerce_product_options_downloads
3. woocommerce_product_options_tax
4. woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data